# React styled-component button does not receive focus

Tags: reactjs, focus, styled-components

#### React styled-component button does not receive focus

This is some code I inherited (see below). There are rows with a title and corresponding button (Bookmark). Using the `tab` button I can focus on the title. Upon another `tab` the focus moves to the styled button, but there is no focus ring. On the next `tab` the focus goes to the next title with a focus ring, and so on.

Why is the styled.button not receiving focus?

If the IconWrapper styled component (listed below) is replaced with `<button></button>` then the 
icon receives focus and has a focus ring.

```
<button
    ref={node => (this.removeBookmarkBtns[i] = node)}
    aria-label="Remove bookmark"
    onClick={() => {this.markForRemoval(bookmark, i);}}
    >
    <BookmarkIcon />
</button>
```

### Inherited code

```
import styled from "styled-components";

<div>
    ... irrelevant stuff

    <IconWrapper
        ref={node => (this.removeBookmarkBtns[i] = node)}
        aria-label="Remove bookmark"
        onClick={() => {this.markForRemoval(bookmark, i);}}
    >
        <BookmarkIcon />
    </IconWrapper>

    ... irrelevant stuff
</div>
```

#### The associated button styled-components

```
const IconWrapper = styled.button`
    color: ${theme.colors.primary};
    font-size: 2em;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 10px;
    background-color: Transparent;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
`;

const BookmarkIcon = styled(Icons.BookmarkCheck)`
    display: block;
    overflow: visible;
`;
```

#### Icon.BookmarkCheck

```
Icons.BookmarkCheck = props => (
    <SVG {...props}>
        <path d="m256 512a254.4 ...
    </SVG>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `tabIndex={0}`?

```
<button
    ref={node => (this.removeBookmarkBtns[i] = node)}
    aria-label="Remove bookmark"
    onClick={() => {this.markForRemoval(bookmark, i);}}
tabIndex={0}
    />
```

Comment: Yes, like this and in the styled-component. Also set it on the Icon. Didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of rubber ducking it dawned on me that it isn't the styled-component causing the problem, but the CSS of the styled-component.

Remove `outline: none` and of course it works.